# Why does media show up in Final Cut but errors when rendering in Compressor?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

I am building a video using media all on my local hard drive. When I watch the video preview in Final Cut, there's no missing media clips. However, when I bring the project into Compressor, the clips are missing and there's some areas where there's a red screen and camera, signifying missing media.

My question is, why does the media have no problem showing up in the Final Cut preview window yet when I export to compressor, it doesn't work out. Are effects in Final Cut screwing up the media when it makes it to Compressor?

Thanks for the help - I'm in a crunch on this project, and can't figure out why Compressor says media is missing.

Comment: Do you go File > Send to > Compressor? Also, have you rendered all media in FCP before opening Compressor?

Answer (score 1):

Is your Final Cut event using proxy media? It's possible the original media has been moved and Compressor can't find it.